# ClearInterval not working (vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval, cleartimeout

Here's the setup. I'm looking to stop the looper (setInterval()) from running after 5 seconds.

I have lots of comments so it should be fairly easy to understand, just ask me any questions for clarification.

I have tried moving the if statement (that checks the timer value === 5000) around. Tried it inside the setInterval function, tried in the onClick function.

I have also tried running setInterval() and clearInterval() prefixed with window.

Any ideas folks?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var looper;
    var degrees = 0;
    var timer = 0; // timer used to monitor how long the wheel has been spinning

    function startWheelAnimation(elementId, speed) {
        // 1. get the element to rotate
        const ele = document.getElementById(elementId); // get the HTML element to rotate
        const cssRotateVal = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)"; // the CSS style rotate value
        
        // 2. CSS3 browser compatibility checks
        if (navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")) {
            ele.style.WebkitTransform = cssRotateVal;
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
            ele.style.MozTransform = cssRotateVal;
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
            ele.style.msTransform = cssRotateVal;
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
            ele.style.OTransform = cssRotateVal;
        } else {
            ele.style.transform = cssRotateVal;
        }
        
        // 3. start looping at the rate of speed var
        looper = setInterval( ()=>{
            // at the rate of speed var run the following code
            startWheelAnimation( elementId, speed );
        }, 
        speed);
        
        degrees++; // increment the degrees value by 1
        timer++; // increment the timer value by 1
        console.log(timer); // devtool

        if (degrees > 359) { // reset the degrees value back to 0 upon a full rotation
            degrees = 0;
            clearInterval(looper); // stop the wheel spinning
        }

        if (timer === 5000) { // after 5 seconds has passed reset the timer and stop the looper
                console.log(looper);
                timer = 0;
                clearInterval(looper); // stop the wheel spinning
            }
    }
    document.getElementById('spinButton').addEventListener("click", event => {
        const speed = 100;
        startWheelAnimation("wheel", speed);
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't know much about the animation thing in vanilla JS but I see a recursive function here which I don't see how will terminate for all the function calls in the stack with the clearinteval() calls 

Comment: All comments and answers aside, you must also look into `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: the accepted answer has the solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create a new `setTimerInterval` in *each* execution of the function. This will accumulate different active intervals, and you'll only have the reference to the *last* one you created.

Instead move that piece of code *out* of the function, and place it in the event handler you have as `addEventListener` call back:

```
document.getElementById('spinButton').addEventListener("click", event => {
    const speed = 100;
    const elementid = "wheel";
    // schedule the repeated run:
    looper = setInterval( ()=>{
        // at the rate of speed var run the following code
        startWheelAnimation(elementid, speed );
    }, 
    speed);
    // also run it immediately
    startWheelAnimation(elementid, speed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After each iteration - `startWheelAnimation` call, you create a new `setInterval` instance recursively (!) and assign it to `looper`. Therefore `clearInterval` only clears the most recent instance.

One fix would be to check if `degrees` or `timer` are set to their starting value:

```
if (degrees == 0 || timer == 0) {
    looper = setInterval( ()=>{
        // at the rate of speed var run the following code
        startWheelAnimation( elementId, speed );
    }, 
    speed);
}
```